# MATLAB - Editing a portion of a matrix with conditions

Tags: matlab, matrix, compiler-errors, conditional-statements, edit

I know that editing a matrix with conditions is done this way:

```
X = [1 1 0 0; 
     0 0 1 1; 
     1 0 1 0; 
     0 0 1 0]

X(X==0) = 1
```

I want to apply the conditional changes only to the lower half of the matrix and I've tried doing this.

```
X(3:4,1:4)(X==0) = 1;
```

But an error is returned: "Error:  Invalid array indexing."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your logical indexing condition is `X==0`.

You can modify this logical index such that the half you don't want to modify is false.

```
idx = (X==0);       % condition
idx(1:2,:) = false; % don't modify rows 1-2 with this index
X( idx ) = 1;       % modify the array according to elements where idx is true
```

You can define `idx` in one line if you want, although this is probably less clear

```
idx = (X==0) & ((1:size(X,1)).' >= 3); % define condition including row number >= 3
X( idx ) = 1;
```